# What's exactly meant if one is saying that the closure of a multivalued operator is the generator of a $C^0$-semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators, multivalued-functions

Let

- $E$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $A$ be a subspace of $E\times E$ and $$\mathcal D(A):=\left\{x\in E\mid\exists y\in E:(x,y)\in A\right\}$$
- $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a contractive $C^0$-semigroup on $\overline{\mathcal D(A)}$

> $A$ is considered as being a multivalued operator. What's meant by "the closure $\overline A$ of $A$ is a generator of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$"?

Is this related to the concept of a "full generator"? My assumption is that the meaning of the sentence is $$\overline A=\left\{(f,g)\in\overline{\mathcal D(A)}\times\overline{\mathcal D(A)}:T(t)f-f=\int_0^tT(s)g\:{\rm d}s\text{ for all }t\ge0\right\}.\tag1$$

> Is that correct? Is that what it's meant?

If so, what can we say about existence and uniqueness of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ and $A$? And is $\overline A$ "single-valued" (which means that $(0,y)\in\overline A$ implies $y=0$)?

---

*Remark*: I've seen the terminology used in Theorem 8.2 of Chapter 4 in [Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence by Ethier and Kurtz](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316658):

[image: Theorem 8.2]

Comment: How many questions run through your mind in a given day?

Comment: Can you give some more context and/or an example where this kind of terminology is used?

Comment: @MaoWao It's used in Theorem 8.2 of Chapter 4 in [Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence by Ethier and Kurtz](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316658).

Comment: There is a notion of *pre*-semigroups for which multi-valued generators make sense (defined in the expected way). However, I don't see how this fits into the context of this theorem. In fact, what you wrote down is exactly the usual single-valued generator of $(T_t)$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MaoWao No, it's not. If $E=\mathcal L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $$(T(t)f)(x):=f(x+t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R\text{ and }f\in E.$$ Then, $$(0,g)\in\left\{(f,g)\in E\times E:T(t)f-f=\int_0^tT(s)g\:{\rm d}s\text{ for all }t\ge0\right\}$$ for all $g\in E$ with $g=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: This semigroup is not strongly continuous ($\lVert T(t)\delta_0-\delta_0\rVert_\infty=1$ for $t>0$).

Comment: @MaoWao You're right. However, $(1)$ shouldn't be the single-valued generator $(\mathcal D(B),B)$ of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$. We should only have that $(f,Bf)$  belongs to the right-hand side of $(1)$ for all $f\in\mathcal D(B)$.